# Reordering rows in TableView would reset to default after data refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, file-manager

I implement a table view which it shows a list of documents

[image]

I implement reordering feature on it with this code

```
var documents = [PDFDocument]()
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let movedObject = self.documents[sourceIndexPath.row]

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    documents.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

    documents.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    NSLog("%@", "\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row) \(documents)")



    do {


        let document = documents[sourceIndexPath.row]
        let documentURL = document.documentURL?.absoluteString


        let document_Dest = documents[destinationIndexPath.row]
        let documentURL_Dest = document_Dest.documentURL?.absoluteString

        try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: documentURL!, toPath: documentURL_Dest!)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
    }




    // To check for correctness enable: self.tableView.reloadData()
   refreshData()

}


  private func refreshData() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

It works completely fine in reordering but the problem is when I close the application and start it again(any time refresh data function runs), rows comes back to their default places. while I need to have saved the changes in reordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering in tableView is specific to tableView only. This reordering doesn't effect the original data source. Once you close the app and run again the method to reload data get the original data from document directory. You need to change the order from this original file as and when this order change in tableView.

1. Get data from Document Directory.

   ```
   private func refreshData() 
   {
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
       documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) }
   }
   ```
2. Create a dictionary with key as document directory file or folder name and value as index.

   ```
   private func refreshData() 
   {
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
       documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) 


       let index = 0
       let documentDic = NSMutableDictionary()
       for element in documents
       {
            documentDic.setValue(index, forKey: element.documentURL?.absoluteString) 
            index = index + 1
       }  

   }
   ```
3. Save this in user Defaults

   ```
   private func refreshData() 
   {
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       let contents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
       documents = contents.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: $0) 

       let index = 0
       let documentDic = NSMutableDictionary()
       for element in documents
       {
            documentDic.setValue(index, forKey: element.documentURL?.absoluteString) 
            index = index + 1
       }  


       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(documentDic, forKey: "ReorderingFormat")
   }
   ```
4. Once user reorder change the value in dictionary corresponding to each url.

   ```
   //Read data from User Defaults
   let dic = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Reordering Format")
   for element in documents
   {
       //This way you get the order or index number for any directory.
       dic.objectForKey(element)
   }
   ```
5. When user get into app again manage your array according to this dictionary value stored in nsuserdefaults.

Comment: Really really thank you for your care. I am completely new and confused what to do exactly. is it possible to explain more please? how I can do something to reorder the original data from document directory? when refresh data function runs then it should not affect on list

Comment: I think implicitly its not possible to sort document directory but you can add another column to files naming - Index and when user change or reorder in tableview you need to update the same in index column. Then sort the files and you will get your required result.

Comment: is it possible for you to edit my codes the way you suggest? or can you recommend me any step by step tutorial ? thank you ver very much. appreciate

Comment: thank you very very much, it has some errors and after fixing errors it still reset back to its default after refreshing Data, my question is that how I can read `userDefault` for showing table? I searched a lot but I did not find the exact codes, please update if possible, thank you thousand times

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh I updated my code for reading user default and this is something logical so you need to code according to your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155869/discussion-between-nupur-gupta-and-neda-derakhshesh).